# How to Sort Numbers within Sorted Column VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

So I have four columns of data, but only two (Column C and D) that I wish to sort.  One column is a list of Work Center Names (Column C) and the other is Operation Numbers (Column D).  What I want to know is how to sort the Work Center Names in Alphabetical Order and then within each Work Center Name, Sort the Operation Numbers in Ascending Order.

So the Data would end up looking like: (assuming x is a random column value)

```
x   x   LDHF   10
x   x   LDHF   20
x   x   LDHF   30
x   x   SHFT   10
x   x   SHFT   20
x   x   SHFT   30
```

Currently, this is my code.  It sorts one column but then when it sorts the second, it overwrites the first sort and scrambles the other column.

```
   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Percent").Sort.SortFields.Clear
   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Percent").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
      "D1:D" & DailyLastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
      xlSortNormal
   With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Percent").Sort
      .SetRange Range("A1:D" & DailyLastRow)
      .Header = xlNo
      .MatchCase = False
      .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
      .SortMethod = xlPinYin
      .Apply
      End With 

   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Percent").Sort.SortFields.Clear
   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Percent").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
      "C1:C" & DailyLastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
      xlSortNormal
   With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Percent").Sort
      .SetRange Range("A1:D" & DailyLastRow)
      .Header = xlNo
      .MatchCase = False
      .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
      .SortMethod = xlPinYin
      .Apply
      End With
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use range.sort.

You have option to define multiple column to sort with `key1 := range.columns(3),  key2 := range.columns(4)`

Here is the table before

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4

x       x       LDHF    30

x       x       SHFT    10
x       x       LDHF    20
x       x       SHFT    20
x       x       SHFT    30
x       x       LDHF    10
```

Here is the script

```
Sub RangeSort()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("a1:D7")

rng.Sort key1:="Col3", order1:=xlAscending, Key2:="Col4", Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

And this is the output :

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
x       x       LDHF    10
x       x       LDHF    20
x       x       LDHF    30
x       x       SHFT    10
x       x       SHFT    20
x       x       SHFT    30
```

I guess it is what you wanted.

Comment: Could you explain a little further?

Comment: I just tried to use that code and for some reason the numbers remain out of order, although the workcenters are correctly alphabetized.  I am not sure what is wrong with the code, but this is what I used: `Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A1:D" & DailyLastRow)
rng.Sort key1:=Range("C1:C" & DailyLastRow), order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("D1:D" & DailyLastRow), Header:=xlYes`

Comment: you wanna sort col 3 after you sort col 4 ?  this means you will get '10 10 20 20 30 30' and then   'LDHF SHDF LDHF SHDF LDHF SHDF'

Comment: Sorry I just corrected it.  I used the code correct in my sub, I just typed it in wrong here.

Comment: Then try this set rng = Range("A1:D" & DailyLastRow)    rng.Sort key1:=rng.Columns(3), order1:=xlAscending, key2:=rng.Columns(4), Header:=xlYes

Comment: Also, check if you have already enter a custom sort on your sheet, then delete it if that is the case

Comment: Ok so the second code did not sort the code at all.  However, the first code seemed to be sorting the code correctly, but somehow getting mixed up halfway through.
Instead of something like
`30 CLEAN 
35 CLEAN 
50 CLEAN 
55 CLEAN 
70 CLEAN 
99 CLEAN 
110 CLEAN 
145 CLEAN 
155 CLEAN 
170 CLEAN 
220 CLEAN `

I would get `110 CLEAN 
145 CLEAN 
155 CLEAN 
170 CLEAN 
220 CLEAN 
30 CLEAN 
35 CLEAN 
50 CLEAN 
55 CLEAN 
70 CLEAN 
99 CLEAN `

Comment: And some of the Work Centers above and below the CLEAN Work Center would be correct and some would be mixed up halfway through like the example above

Answer (score 0):

use the below code. This will do your job. Let me know if it does not work.

```
Sub PSortData()

    Dim rngData As Range

    Set rngData = Worksheets("Percent").Range("A1:D" & DailyLastRow)

    rngData.Sort Key1:=Range("C1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("D1"), Order2:=xlAscending, _
    Header:=xlNo, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal, DataOption3:=xlSortNormal

    Set rngData = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this code sorts the data pretty much the same as the code I posted above.  It sorts one column or the other, not one within the other.

Comment: @ksmit144 what is it you looking for then? Could you re-iterate your question?